# Capture context menus in Snip & Sketch

Tags: windows-10, snipping

In the built in Windows Snipping Tool, if you want to capture context menus that disappear when you move the mouse off of them, you can start a new snip, then press ESC, then expand your context menu, then press Ctrl-PrtScn to trigger a snip of your screen.

In Windows 10 when I open the Snipping Tool I am being reminded that I should use Snip & Sketch instead. But how do you capture the context menus in Snip & Sketch? (ESC then Ctrl-PrtScn does not work.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you can tell Snip & Sketch to take a snip in 3 or 10 seconds in the New menu. You click the down-arrow at the end of the New button and choose the option you want.

Second, you can tell the <kbd>Print Screen</kbd> key on your computer to open Snip & Sketch by opening Settings in Snip & Sketch, clicking **Use the PrtScn button to open screen snipping**. This opens the **Keyboard** Settings app. Scroll down a bit and enable **Print Screen shortcut.**

For more granular controls, you will need to use a third-party application such as Greenshot or ShareX (my preferred screen shot utility).

Comment: My version of Snip & Sketch doesn't have the drop down for the delay (perhaps my company hasn't rolled out the latest update yet), but the Print Screen option works well.  (Which I setup through the Ease of Access Windows setting.) Thx.

Comment: Snip & Sketch was only first released with the most recent build of Windows 10, 1809. I'm not aware of any updates to the app yet.

Comment: Hmmm. My Snip & Sketch version is 10.1806.2112.0.

Comment: Are you running Insider Preview perhaps?

Comment: My Windows version is 1809. (And not insider preview.) I found this link stating you need 10.1807 to have delay in Snip & Sketch: https://www.reddit.com/r/Windows10/comments/9kwqrt/snip_sketch_is_missing_one_useful_feature_delay/

Comment: Is the Store blocked in your environment? If not, have you opened it to check for updates to installed apps?

Comment: Ahah! The store isn't blocked but it turns out our windows updates (including store apps) are managed by IT; the upgrade address is pointed to our intranet, which doesn't have the latest version. If need be I could put in a ticket to temporarily allow me to update the store app. But with Print Screen working it's not a big deal.